# C Exercise - Loop - Unexpected output: Empty lines

Tags: c, loops, line

I would like to know, why there are empty lines printed in the places specified in the output.
It doesnt make sense to me because this would mean that the loop continues even though the test condition is false. (This is the 9th Review Question of the 6th Chapter in "C Primer Plus")

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int n, m;

    n = 30;
    while (++n <= 33)
        printf("%d|",n);

    n = 30;
    do
        printf("%d|",n);
    while (++n <= 33);

    printf("\n***\n");

    for (n = 1; n*n < 200; n += 4)
        printf("%d\n", n);       // Why will this print an empty line at the end?

    printf("\n***\n");

    for (n = 2, m = 6; n < m; n *= 2, m+= 2)
        printf("%d %d\n", n, m); // and this

    printf("\n***\n");

    for (n = 5; n > 0; n--)
    {
        for (m = 0; m <= n; m++)
            printf("=");
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Produces the output:

```
31|32|33|30|31|32|33|
***
1
5
9
13
                            (<= Why is there an empty line here?)
***
2 6
4 8
8 10
                            (<= and here?)
***
======
=====
====
===
==
```

Comment: You're just printing an extra `\n` in `printf("\n***\n");` (at the beginning).

Comment: Because you print an empty line before the `***` in `printf("\n***\n");`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This adds a new line after the digit:

```
printf("%d\n", n);
```

This adds a new line before the asterisks:

```
printf("\n***\n");
```

If I understand you correctly you want to just write:

```
printf("***\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

These two lines:

```
printf("%d\n", n);
printf("\n***\n");
```

reduce, on the final iteration of your loop, to

```
printf("%d\n\n***\n", n);
```

`\n\n` will print a blank line